# Почему линковщик не видит символ?

Tags: c++

В начале файла `dllmain.cpp` есть такой фрагмент кода: `extern "C" HINSTANCE hAppInstance;`. При линковке вылетает ошибка `LNK2001  unresolved external symbol _hAppInstance    C:\...\dllmain.obj`, но никаких `_hAppInstance` в проекте нет. Есть только hAppInstance, который используется в dllmain.cpp и который объявлен. MSDN говорит, что LNK2001 появляется если символ не объявлен (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2001?view=vs-2019). Что не так с объявлением `hAppInstance` и почему линковщик не видит его?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

При записи "в одну строчку", т.е. без `{}`

```
extern "C" HINSTANCE hAppInstance;
```

является *объявлением*, но не *определением* переменной. Без определения разумеется будет LNK2001.

- Либо добавьте отдельное определение (после этого объявления)

  ```
  extern "C" HINSTANCE hAppInstance;
  HINSTANCE hAppInstance;
  ```
- Либо превратите это объявление в определение путем добавления явного инициализатора

  ```
  extern "C" HINSTANCE hAppInstance = 0;
  ```
- Либо превратите это объявление в определение путем добавления `{}`

  ```
  extern "C" { HINSTANCE hAppInstance; }
  ```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Получается, определение - это обьявление с инициализацией?

Comment: Чем отличается обьявление в глобальной области видимости от обьявление в локальной области видимость? Или это лучше задать как отдельный вопрос?

Comment: @J.Huxley Если *"Есть только hAppInstance, который используется в dllmain.cpp"* то вам наверное стоит сделать `static HINSTANCE hAppInstance`.

Comment: @J. Huxley: Нет, не обязательно с инициализацией. Простое `HINSTANCE hAppInstance;` - это тоже определение, хоть в нем и нет явной инициализации. Но добавление `extern` превращает определение в объявление. И превратить его обратно в определение (именно в этом случае) можно добавлением явного инициализатора.